How to find the characteristic form of coupled PDEs?
I'm reading a textbook named linear and nonlinear waves. In chap.14, a method was used to solve the coupled equations which can reduce PDEs to ODEs. But I don't know how to find the needed characteristic form in this method. Here's the content in the book:

We have two coupled PDEs:
$$
\frac{\partial k}{\partial t} + \omega_0'(k) \frac{\partial k}{\partial x} + 
\omega_2(k) \frac{\partial a^2}{\partial x} = 0 \\
\frac{\partial a^2}{\partial t} + \omega_0'(k) \frac{\partial a^2}{\partial x} +
\omega_0''(k) a^2 \frac{\partial k}{\partial x} = 0
$$
The characteristic form of these two equation is:
$$
\frac12 \left( \frac{\omega_0''(k)}{\omega_2(k)} \right)^{1/2} d k \pm d a = 0
$$
on characteristics:
$$
\frac{d x}{d t} = \omega_0'(k) \pm \left[ \omega_2(k) \omega_0''(k) \right]^{1/2} a
$$

I know how to derive the characteristics, but how about the characteristic form?

Did you compute the left eigenvectors as well as the eigenvalues/characteristics?

Just follow example 1, p. 117. Let $a^{2} = A$. Then the linear combination
\begin{align}
l_{1} (k_{t} + \omega_{0}' k_{x} + \omega_{2} A_{x}) + l_{2} (A_{t} + \omega_{0}' A_{x} + \omega_{0}'' A k_{x}) = 0
\end{align}
takes the characteristic form
\begin{align}
l_{1} \frac{dk}{dt} + l_{2} \frac{dA}{dt} &= l_{1} (k_{t} + c k_{x}) + l_{2} (A_{t} + c A_{x}) \\
&= 0 \tag 1
\end{align}
provided
\begin{align}
\omega_{0}' l_{1} + \omega_{0}'' A l_{2} &= c l_{1} \\
\omega_{2} l_{1}  + \omega_{0}' l_{2} &= c l_{2} \tag 2
\end{align}
This system has a unique solution if the determinant vanishes i.e
$$(\omega_{0}' - c)^{2} - \omega_{0}'' \omega_{2} A = 0 \implies c = \omega_{0}' \pm (\omega_{0}'' \omega_{2} A)^{1/2} =: \frac{dx}{dt}$$
Substituting this result into $(2)$ and solving gives
$$(l_{1}, l_{2}) = s \left( (\omega_{0}'' A)^{1/2}, \ \pm (\omega_{2})^{1/2} \right), \quad s \in \mathbb{R}$$
As such, from $(1)$, the characteristic form is
\begin{align}
0 &= l_{1} \frac{dk}{dt} + l_{2} \frac{dA}{dt} \\
&= \left( \omega_{0}'' A \right)^{1/2} \frac{dk}{dt} \pm (\omega_{2})^{1/2} \frac{dA}{dt} \\
&= \text{sgn}(a) \left( \omega_{0}'' \right)^{1/2} a \frac{dk}{dt} \pm 2 a (\omega_{2})^{1/2} \frac{da}{dt}
\end{align}
and hence
$$\frac{1}{2} \text{sgn}(a) \left( \frac{\omega_{0}''}{\omega_{2}} \right)^{1/2} dk \pm da = 0$$
